# Taking the average of rows from different series in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a hard time with a simple task. I have two series created like this:

```
stu1 = pd.Series({'1130': 82, '1430': 85, '2430': 78, '2431': 82})
stu2 = pd.Series({'1130': 98, '1430': 95, '2333': 96, '2530': 88})
```

The keys in the dictionaries (`1130...`) represent course numbers, and the values represent the grades for these students. I am trying to average the grades for each course across the two students and print the results. I have searched the internet pretty exhaustively without result, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want an average based off of all courses or only matching courses?

Comment: all courses! but on the non matching courses, it will only be an average of one number of course

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Comment: By average do you mean mean, median, mode - or some other average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `concat` before `mean`

```
s = pd.concat([stu1, stu2]).mean(level=0)
s
Out[122]: 
1130    90
1430    90
2430    78
2431    82
2333    96
2530    88
dtype: int64
```